# How to create anchors on the fly or how to modify exiting ones using jscript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have numerous URIs displayed in a scrollable html table. When I hover over the first file name the actual image will display as a tooltip (with the help of some jQuery code) next to the name because I have an anchor hard-coded to do just that. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how create or modify anchors via javascript or jQuery on ther fly, so I need help.

Here is the one hard coded anchor that works just fine for a specific URI:

```
< a id="a$ci" class="screenshot" rel="http://www.xyz/ge/XpixColona003.png" title="XpixColona003.png">XpixColona003< /a>
```

I would be very happy id someone could show me how to modify the rel the title and text of the anchor with javascript or jQuery, or, show me how to create the correct anchor for every URI anew.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Alex

Comment: Special characters are not legal element IDs. The only ones allowed are letters followed by numbers, hyphens, colons, underscores and periods

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").hover(function(){
   var anc = $(this);
   anc.attr("src","new value");
   anc.attr("rel","new value");
   anc.attr("title","new value");
});
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer, however I also need to know how can I invoke the jQuery function from within the html code.

Comment: @user1874675 just add <script> tag in your html